# jquery ajaxError post url to new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I am using Laravel and my webpage contains lots of ajax call. To enable easier debugging, I want the jquery to open the problematic url on new page to show the complete error message generated by Laravel.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings,exception ){
    if(exception =="Internal Server Error"){
        window.location.href=settings.url;
    }
});
```

It works well in showing problematic get url on new page. However, how can I show the post url on new page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open). Note that this may results in your new window being blocked.

Comment: My question is how to get the problematic post request from last ajax call, and re-post the URL on new page.